# How make bash getopts not recognize option as a option argument

Tags: bash, getopts

In my bash script, I would like to use `getopts` to parse command-line options.

My first attempt, to learn how to use it, is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

v_option_arg=""
r_option_arg=""
h_option_arg=""

function get_opt_args() {
    while getopts ":v:r:h:" opt
    do
        case $opt in
        "v")
            v_option_arg="$OPTARG"
             ;;
        "h")
            h_option_arg="$OPTARG"
            ;;
        "r")
            r_option_arg="$OPTARG"
            ;;
        "?")
            echo "Unknown option -$OPTARG"
            exit 1
            ;;
        ":")
            echo "No argument value for option -$OPTARG"
            ;;
        *)
            # Should not occur
            echo "Unknown error while processing options"
            ;;
        esac
    done
    shift $((OPTIND-1))
}

get_opt_args $@
if [ ! -z "$v_option_arg" ]; then
    echo "Argnument value for option -v: $v_option_arg"
fi
if [ ! -z "$r_option_arg" ]; then
    echo "Argnument value for option -r: $r_option_arg"
fi
if [ ! -z "$h_option_arg" ]; then
    echo "Argnument value for option -h: $h_option_arg"
fi
```

```
$ bash testopts.sh -v 1
Argnument value for option -v: 1
$ bash testopts.sh -r 2
Argnument value for option -r: 2
$ bash testopts.sh -h 3
Argnument value for option -h: 3
$ bash testopts.sh -v 1 -r 2 -h 3
Argnument value for option -v: 1
Argnument value for option -r: 2
Argnument value for option -h: 3
$ bash testopts.sh -v
No argument value for option -v
$ bash testopts.sh -a
Unknown option -a
```

This seems to work successfully.

Next, I test my script's robustness by omitting an argument:

```
$ bash testopts.sh -v -r 2
Argnument value for option -v: -r
```

This is not what I was expecting.  How can I make it distinguish the differences of one option and one option argument?

I want to make my script more robust, so that if one option is given without its argument, I can emit a suitable error message.

Note: Each option must have a option argument.

Can I do this with just `getopts`?

Comment: You declared the -v option as requiring an argument. So `getopt` considers `-r` as the mandatory argument of option `-v`. If you want `-v` to have an optional argument use `v::` instead of `v:` in the optstring.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet The `::` behaviour is a GNU extension, and not POSIX standard.

Comment: @rojomoke You're right.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet, Thanks very much. But each option must have a option argument.

Comment: Please use actual, selectable text rather than images of text.  Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From `man bash`, SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS, getopts:

> optstring contains the option characters to be recognized; if a character is followed by a colon, the option is expected to have an argument, which should be separated from it by white space.

From your script:

```
while getopts ":v:r:h:" opt
```

You told `bash` explicitly that `-v` expects an argument. In the case of `-v -r 2`, `-r` is the argument to `-v`, with `2` remaining as non-option argument to the script.

Works as designed, and this is the limit of `getopts` abilities.

What you *can* do is checking if the argument to `-v` is numeric (as it seems that is what your script expects), and in the given case inform the user that `-v` *does* require a number, and that `-r` isn't it. But that is something your script needs to do in the `"v")` case, not something `getopts` can handle.

```
    case $opt in
    "v")
        v_option_arg="$OPTARG"
        if [[ ! "${v_option_arg}" =~ ^[0-9]*$ ]]
        then
            echo "Error: Option '-v' expects numeric argument, you gave: ${v_option_arg}"
            exit 1
        fi
         ;;
```

Comment: OK, I get it. Thanks for your patients.